# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' in Linux when QuantConnect.pythonnet PythonEngine.Initialize()

Tags: python, .net

I use QuantConnect.pythonnet (Python.Runtime.dll) to call python.
But failed **in linux** when PythonEngine.Initialize().
result is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'"

I failed to configure the virtual environment with Virtualenv and conda, and the error was No module named 'encodings'

Who has successful experience in **linux** configuration, please share, thank you!

#### error

```
/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python310.zip;/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10;/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload;/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages;~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/bin/python'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    '/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python310.zip;/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10;/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload;/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages;~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f348e961740 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

#### code

```
using Python.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyPyTools
{

    public class Program
    {
        // 使用pyperclip剪切板
        // pip install pyperclip

        private static string pyString =
            "import clr\n" +
            "import pyperclip\n" +
            "from MyPyTools import GLContext\n" +
            "\n" +
            "print(GLContext.GetValue('hello'))\n" +
            "GLContext.SetValue('abc', 'def')\n" +
            "\n" +
            "GLContext.Set2Clip('我来自剪切板')\n" +
            "\n" +
            "pyperclip.copy(GLContext.Copy2Clip())" +
            "\n";

        public void SetEnv()
        {
            // https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Using-Python.NET-with-Virtual-Environments

            var pathToVirtualEnv = @"path\to\env";
            
            // be sure not to overwrite your existing "PATH" environmental variable.
            var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").TrimEnd(';');
            path = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? pathToVirtualEnv : path + ";" + pathToVirtualEnv;
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathToVirtualEnv, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", pathToVirtualEnv, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", $"{pathToVirtualEnv}\\Lib\\site-packages;{pathToVirtualEnv}\\Lib", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

            PythonEngine.PythonHome = pathToVirtualEnv;
            PythonEngine.PythonPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            string winPath = @"D:\tools\python310";
            string linuxPath = "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310";
            
            
            if(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                string pathToVirtualEnv = winPath;
                Runtime.PythonDLL = Path.Combine(pathToVirtualEnv, "python310.dll");
                PythonEngine.PythonHome = Path.Combine(pathToVirtualEnv, "python.exe");
                PythonEngine.PythonPath = @$"{pathToVirtualEnv}\Lib\site-packages;{pathToVirtualEnv}\Lib;{pathToVirtualEnv}\DLLs";

            }
            else if(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                //Virtualenv
                var pathToVirtualEnv = "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py310";

                Runtime.PythonDLL = $"{pathToVirtualEnv}/lib/libpython3.10.so";
                
                var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").TrimEnd(';');
                path = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? pathToVirtualEnv : path + ";" + pathToVirtualEnv;
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathToVirtualEnv, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", pathToVirtualEnv, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", $"{pathToVirtualEnv}/lib/python310.zip;{pathToVirtualEnv}/lib/python3.10;{pathToVirtualEnv}/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload;{pathToVirtualEnv}/lib/python3.10/site-packages;~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

                var pythonpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);;
                Console.WriteLine(pythonpath);
                PythonEngine.PythonHome = $"{pathToVirtualEnv}/bin/python";
                //PythonEngine.PythonHome = $"{pathToVirtualEnv}";
                PythonEngine.PythonPath = pythonpath;

                

            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("This OS is not support");
                return;
            }

            PythonEngine.Initialize();
            //使用第三方库
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
                Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

                dynamic sin = np.sin;
                Console.WriteLine(sin(5));

                double c = (double)(np.cos(5) + sin(5));
                Console.WriteLine(c);

                dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
                Console.WriteLine(a);

                dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, dtype: np.int32);
                Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);

                Console.WriteLine(a * b);
            }


            //调用无参无返回值方法
            using (Py.GIL()) //执行python的调用应该放在using (Py.GIL())块内
            {
                //python对象应声明为dynamic类型
                dynamic np = Py.Import("test");
                np.hello();
            }
            //调用有参有返回值方法
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic np = Py.Import("test");
                int r = np.add(1, 2);
                Console.WriteLine($"计算结果{r}");
            }

            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic pd = Py.Import("pandas");
                var pd_csv = pd.read_csv("D:\\Data\\Bar\\Daily\\2020\\2020-03-03.csv");
                Console.WriteLine(pd_csv.ToString());
            }

            PythonEngine.RunSimpleString(pyString);
            string value = GLContext.GetValue("abc");
            Console.WriteLine(value);

            var result = PythonEngine.RunSimpleString("print('Hello from Python!')");
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            PythonEngine.Shutdown();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


    }
}
```

OS: ubuntu 2210
python: python 3.10.11
test env：Virtualenv, conda,